# Delay between multiple ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 ajax calls that look like this (not posting all five):

```
tabTest = {
BASE_URL : 'http://localhost/project/',
getPics : function(){

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : this.BASE_URL +'js/image1.js',
        dataType : "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            var pic = data.images.image[0].image_one;
                $('#pic1 img').attr("src", pic);
        }   
    });
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : this.BASE_URL +'js/image2.js',
        dataType : "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            var pic = data.images.image[0].image_two;           
                $('#pic2 img').attr("src", pic);
        }   
    });
   }
};
```

The ajax calls do work but they all fire at once; instead, I need to put a delay between each one so they do not fire all at once but rather in order only once (upon click, which happens in a different function) with 5 seconds between each call.

I've tried using 'setTimeout' but it has not worked yet.  I'm really not sure how to proceed on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put your AJAX calls its own `setTimeout()` there's no reason why it shouldn't work:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : this.BASE_URL +'js/image1.js',
        dataType : "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            var pic = data.images.image[0].image_one;
            $('#pic1 img').attr("src", pic);
        }   
    });
}, 5000);
```

And then increment the duration by 5000 for each call. So the second would look like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : this.BASE_URL +'js/image2.js',
        dataType : "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            var pic = data.images.image[0].image_one;
            $('#pic2 img').attr("src", pic);
        }   
    });
}, 10000);
```

You could also put the functions inside the previous request's callback although a request fail would mean that all subsequent AJAX requests wouldn't get called.

Comment: Wrapping the ajax calls inside of setTimeout worked.  I had tried this solution before but because I'm so tired, I can't see that any errors I receive were minor in nature (tweaking the URL in the ajax call) and that my original idea was correct. This has happened to me now twice where I find the solution myself, think it doesn't work cause I'm half asleep, post on SOF and have someone like you point out the obvious.  Thanks for waking me up showing me the errors of my ways!

Comment: No problem Max, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add next ajax call on previous success callback function.

```
$.ajax({
type : 'GET',
url : this.BASE_URL +'js/image1.js',
dataType : "json",
async: false,
success: function(data){
    var pic = data.images.image[0].image_one;
        $('#pic1 img').attr("src", pic);
   $.ajax({
      type : 'GET',
      url : this.BASE_URL +'js/image2.js',
      dataType : "json",
      async: false,
      success: function(data){
          var pic = data.images.image[0].image_two;           
              $('#pic2 img').attr("src", pic);
      }   
  });
}
```

});

OR

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : this.BASE_URL +'js/image1.js',
        dataType : "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            var pic = data.images.image[0].image_one;
                $('#pic1 img').attr("src", pic);
            call2();
        }   
    });

function call2(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : this.BASE_URL +'js/image2.js',
        dataType : "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            var pic = data.images.image[0].image_two;           
                $('#pic2 img').attr("src", pic);
        }   
    });
}
```

So now when the first ajax will completed then next call will fire.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval()` for this. When using `setInterval()` it can cal the wat u mention the time for function...u check it out the seconds ...

```
setInterval("functionname()",50000);
```